# ¿Cómo agregar dinámica un fragmento de html dentro de un div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

¿Cómo puedo hacer que un fragmento de codigo html lo pueda agregar de forma dinámica por medio de JavaScript o jQuery, tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```
<section class="flex-container">
                  <div class="flex-item"><img class="Imagenes" src="img/actualizar.png" title="Actualizar" onclick="Actualiza();"/></div>                     
                  <div class="flex-item"><img class="Imagen" src="img/cloud.png" title="Descargar archivos TXT" onclick="Click();"/></div>                                       
</section>
```

El fragmetno que quiero agregar es el siguiente:

```
  <div class="flex-item" style="padding:6px;"><span class="icon-bell"></span><span class="count">1</span></div>
```

para que al final tenga como resultado esto:

```
<section class="flex-container">
             <div class="flex-item"><img class="Imagenes" src="img/actualizar.png" title="Actualizar" onclick="Actualiza();"/></div>                     
              <div class="flex-item"><img class="Imagen" src="img/cloud.png" title="Descargar archivos TXT" onclick="Click();"/></div>
              <div class="flex-item" style="padding:6px;"><span class="icon-bell"></span><span class="count">1</span></div>                                       
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `.append()` de jquery que te permite agregar un elemento en otro:

```js
$("#agregar").click(function(){

 var elemento = '<div class="flex-item" style="padding:6px;"><span class="icon-bell"></span><span class="count">1</span></div>';
 
 $("#contenedor").append(elemento);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="flex-container" id="contenedor">
             <div class="flex-item"><img class="Imagenes" src="img/actualizar.png" title="Actualizar" onclick="Actualiza();"/></div>                     
              <div class="flex-item"><img class="Imagen" src="img/cloud.png" title="Descargar archivos TXT" onclick="Click();"/></div>
                                                    
 </section>
 
 <button id='agregar'>Agregar div</button>
```

Recuerda agregarle un id al div donde deseas que se agrege porque si lo haces pro clase, se agregara a todos los elementos con esa clase.

Nota: Puse el elemento nuevo como un string porque no se especifico de donde viene.

Comment: Lo he probado y es justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias por tu apoyo y por la respuesta que me dio la solución.

Comment: Es muy comodo agregar elementos en un string con el HTML, pero no es una buena practica. Es mejor crear elemento por elemento a irlos agregando poco a poco.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función **`.appendTo()`** de jQuery, sería con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
$('seleccionar-div-a-mover').appendTo('contenedor');
```

En tu caso sería:

```
$('.flex-item').appendTo('.flex-container');
```

Pero debes saber que ese modo en tu caso no sería muy fiable ya que si tienes más elementos con la clase `flex-item` llevarás todos estos elementos al contenedor `flex-container`, para resolver esto invéntate un modo mejor para hacer una referencia más concreta del elemento/s que quieres mover, como por ejemplo usando el atributo `id`.

Espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tomar el tiempo,  me ha servido  de mucho, haré un ejemplo.

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev de nada! Si la respuesta te sirvió de ayuda por favor marcala como aceptada :)